# Why and when to pass vector by reference?

Tags: c++, data-structures, std

I have a question that why to pass vector or string by reference. simply why to pass a value by reference?
let's take a example :-
suppose I want pass a vector in function then I'd write below code:-

```
void fun(vector<string/int>v){
......
......
}
```

so sometime it gives correct output but sometime it gives wrong.

but when I use:-

```
void fun(vector<string/int> & v){
......
......
}
```

then wrong output turns right
so tell me when to use  **&**  and why ?

thank u in advance...

Comment: Can you show us(by giving code example) where it shows wrong output when using pass by value?

Comment: You pass a reference when you want to pass the object itself rather than a copy of it.

Comment: I assume your actual question is "how do I get my code to produce the right answer"? In order to do that we'd need a [mre]

Comment: no, my actual question is what I wrote there....

Answer (score 1):

> Why and when to pass vector by reference?

You should use a reference when you need indirection, and you don't need a pointer.

You may need indirection if

- You need to avoid unnecessary copying.
- You intend to modify the object in-place.
- You need to observe identity (memory address) of the object.

Because:

- Passing a value potentially requires copying that may be avoided by using indirection. Copying can be expensive, such as in the case of vectors.
- Without indirection, you cannot modify the argument in-place.
- If the parameter is a value, then it isn't the same object as the argument and hence they will have a different identities.
- References cannot be null, which makes them easier to use than pointers and hence preferable when the nullability isn't needed.